# Will the var members in case class affect case class's equality?

Tags: scala, equality, case-class, algebraic-data-types

I have made heavy use of case classes in my code, replying on the underlying equality definitions of case class to behave correctly. Then now I found that I need to add another field member to a case class.

1. So if I add a `var` field member in case class, will it mess up the equality attributes for the case class?
2. If 1 is yes, then what if I just change the `var` field value once, after that, no any reassignment will happen, before the case class goes into any collections or do equality comparison, will that still mess up the equality behaviors?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Case class equality is based solely on its primary constructor attributes, whether they're `var` or `val` (yes, you can make them `var` by giving an explicit `var` to override the implied `val` that case class constructor args possess.) Adding properties in the body of a `case class` *does not* influence the compiler-generated `equals(other: Any)` method.

Witness:

```
package rrs.scribble

object  CCVarEq
{
  case class CC1(i: Int, j: Float, var k: Double)

  case class CC2(i: Int, j: Float, var k: Double) {
    var l = math.Pi
  }

  def show {
    val cc11 = CC1(1, 2.0f, 3.0)
    val cc12 = CC1(1, 2.0f, 3.0)

    val cc21 = CC2(1, 2.0f, 3.0); cc21.l = math.E
    val cc22 = CC2(1, 2.0f, 3.0)

    printf("cc11 == cc12: %s%n", cc11 == cc12); cc12.k = math.Pi * math.E
    printf("cc11 == cc12: %s%n", cc11 == cc12)

    printf("cc21 == cc22: %s%n", cc21 == cc22)
  }
}
```

In the REPL:

```
scala> import rrs.scribble.CCVarEq._
import rrs.scribble.CCVarEq._

scala> show
cc11 == cc12: true
cc11 == cc12: false
cc21 == cc22: true
```

And all jamie's points about concurrency are valid, too.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that simple.  You update a case class var on one thread, and another thread is performing an equality check.  Unless the var is volatile, it's plausible that the change to the var won't be propagated to the other thread before the equality check is performed.  So you could have race conditions.  Regardless if this happens only once or many times.

Is the value to be changed once undefined up to that point?  If so, use a lazy val.  It has a synchronization concern that could slow high-performance code, but would otherwise meet your use case.

Comment: I see for the point of race conditions. Thanks for telling me the lazy val, I haven't used it until now, and I do want to delay the initialization of the newly add field, and I guess it won't break anything mentioned....