# Scala error: "reassignment to val" while attempting to modify content?

Tags: scala

I have the following code that reveals the problem:

```
case class Best[T](x: Array[T], y: Double)

def someFunc(byRef : Best[Int]) : Unit = {
   byRef.y = 5
}
```

and I get the error:

```
Multiple markers at this line:

reassignment to val
reassignment to val
```

why is that? I am not attempting to change the reference byRef but its content ...

Comment: If you *really* need to update the value `y` of your `byRef`, you can declare your `y` as `var y : Double`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest way to achieve my use-case and the answer to my OP i.e. what I needed is to mark the case class attributes as `var`:

```
case class Best[T](var x: Array[T], var y: Double)

def someFunc(byRef : Best[Int]) : Unit = {
   byRef.y = 5
}
```

Comment: `case class` can have `var` . See an example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349165/will-the-var-members-in-case-class-affect-case-classs-equality

Answer (score 3):

`case` class arguments are implicitly declared as `val` and are treated as class fields that's why compiler does not allow to change it's value.

Instead of changing it's value you should use `copy` method. Something like:

```
byRef.copy(y = 5)
```

Comment: Use `copy` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

Case classes by default are `immutable`. You can not change it's content.
Instead you can create new case class with modified content:

```
case class Best[T](x: Array[T], y: Double)

def someFunc(byRef : Best[Int]) : Best[Int] = {
   byRef.copy(y = 5)
}
```

To achieve what you need - introduce mutability via simple classes. *Not recommended*

```
  class Worst[T](x: Array[T], var y: Double) {
    override def toString: String = s"$y:${x.toList}"
  }

  def someFunc2(byRef : Worst[Int]) : Unit = {
    byRef.y = 5
  }

  val w = new Worst(Array(1), 1)
  someFunc2(w)
  println(w)
```

Comment: Is there another way not using the return value? I need to modify its content ... how about using a non-case class? I tried that too and didn't work

Comment: added alternative.